# Running first JCStress test

Tags: java, jcstress

I'm new to JCStress and I'm trying to run the "hello world" for JCStress but facing some problems. I think there is some obvious thing that I'm missing.

I'm following [this](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcstress) link to learn. And the samples that I'm trying are [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/tip/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples).

I started with the template project created from the following public maven archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DinteractiveMode=false" "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jcstress" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=jcstress-java-test-archetype" "-DarchetypeVersion=0.4" "-DgroupId=org.sample" "-DartifactId=test" "-Dversion=1.0"
```

I did a `mvn clean install` and got the `.\target\jcstress.jar`. I added `MyConcurrencyTest` which has the following code in package `org.sample`

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jcstress.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jcstress.infra.results.I_Result;


@JCStressTest
@Outcome(id = "1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING, desc = "One update lost: atomicity failure.")
@Outcome(id = "2", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Actors updated independently.")
@State
public class MyConcurrencyTest {

    int v;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        v++;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2() {
        v++;
    }

    @Arbiter
    public void arbiter(I_Result r) {
        r.r1 = v;
    }

}
```

The following is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Now I'm trying to run this using this command (my current directory is the project root directory when I execute this command)

```
java -cp ".\target\classes" -jar .\target\jcstress.jar -v -t org.sample.MyConcurrencyTest
```

But the `org.sample.MyConcurrencyTest` don't get executed.

(I understand that if we don't specify the tests using `-t <testname>` the tests from `jcstress.jar/META-INF/TestList` are picked up.)
I think I'm missing something very obvious. Can someone please help?

(It will be great if someone could share a good starter tutorial on JCStress explaining it's capabilities and functionalities that it has)

Comment: I figured out that after changing `MyConcurrencyTest` I need to do a `mvn clean install` (this will add `MyConcurrencyTest` into the `TestList` file), and then simply run `java -jar .\target\jcstress.jar -v` and it will work. But I still don't know how to run a test using the `-t` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I figured out what I was missing.

We need to do a `mvn clean install` to get `MyConcurrencyTest` into the `META-INF/TestList` file.

Now I can run

```
java -jar .\target\jcstress.jar -v -t org.sample.MyConcurrencyTest
```

and my test get executed. If I want to execute all the tests, I need to do

```
java -jar .\target\jcstress.jar -v
```

That's it. Bingo!!

I was just missing `mvn clean install`, I thought compiling the classes from Intellij and putting them on classpath will work. But it's not the case. You need to tell the JCStress framework what tests you need to execute, and for that you need to compulsorily do a `mvn clean install`.

Comment: that `META-INF` is in `target/classes`, minor addition

Comment: @Eugene Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since 2022, Intelij IDEA has plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19779-jcstress